# pop to first view controller (root view controller ) from third view controller navigationItems are not being changed

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a navigation bar on which I push several views according to what the user selects.Now I need to pop to first view controller from third controller.The applications pop to first view controller but navigationItems are not been changed as it is in second view controller but, I need to change navigationItems.

Code that I used: appdelagte.h

```
Bool isDelete;
@property(nonatomic)Bool isDelete;
```

appDelegate.m

```
@synthesize isDelete;
```

thirdViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(Bool)animated {
  appDelegate.isDelete=YES;
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

secondViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(Bool)animated {
    if(appDelegate.isDelete==YES)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Here pop to first view controller but navigationItems are not being changed as it is in secon view controller

Any one help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

May be you can do this behavior without showing third ctrl? Like do this check `if(appDelegate.isDelete==YES)` in second ctrl.

```
- (void) showThird {
    if(appDelegate.isDelete == NO) {
        MyThirdCtrlClss *ctrl = [[MyThirdCtrlClss alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
        [crel release];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm still for iOS 13.0.. Thanks